# DSL Beta 2 - Connector Moniker - Why is it not in the diagram file?

Tags: c#, dsl, visual-studio-2010, dsl-tools, moniker

I am creating a DSL, I want to associate two Entities with a connector but I do not want the EntityMoniker to be in the underlying XML, I need it to be in the Diagram File. I am not sure why it is not in the Diagram file automatically as that seems to be the place where all information 'about' the diagram is held.

If I remove the element manually then obviously when I open the diagram up again the connection is gone.

I.e

```
  </Methods>
      <EntityAssociation>
        <entityMoniker Name="/6fa571fb-93ba-4f6f-a7ae-9fffee5eb901/Product" />
      </EntityAssociation>
    </Entity>
  </Entities>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that actually the connector is in the diagram, but this is the Presentation object for the relationship which is in the model